# Can I ask questions regarding products related to academia?

Tags: discussion

I am in search of a height adjustable hands free book holder in my country and searched a lot.

My search is unsuccessful. I can get height adjustable orchestral stands, height adjustable laptop stands, but not book/document/copy holders.

Since there is no stack website for product recommendations, I want to know whether this site is a welcoming one to get guidelines related to the product.

Answer (score 13):

Questions about product recommendations are generally considered off-topic, and typically closed as [shopping questions](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3657/20058). The only exception is certain types of [software recommendations](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4675/20058).

Moreover, the product you want to ask about is only very loosely related to the academic work.

Note also that many products get out of market very quickly, substituted by newer models. That's why   Stack Exchange sites are not well suited for product recommendations.