# I asked for a software solution, question was closed as "shopping" - legit?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions, close-reasons, shopping-questions

I asked this:

[How can I generate an elegant (academic) static CV web page?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/188820/7319)

which got a couple of answers, including a very relevant one. The question was closed as a "shopping question", but the very Meta answer explaining what inappropriate shopping questions are [says](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3658/7319) that "seek help choosing, finding or assessing ... a software solution" is *not* inappropriate shopping.

So should my question really have been closed?

Comment: Looks like this got 3 close votes for "shopping question" and 2 for "opinion-based." As you say, software recommendations when related to academia are allowed per [this policy](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4675). Personally, I would vote to reopen if I could do so without hammering it, but curious to see why others feel differently.

Comment: I’ve cast the last reopen vote. Unfortunately, it seems that the policy on software is frequently missed by close-voters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(just writing an answer to get this off our backlog)*

Thanks for posting. Software recommendations are indeed on-topic, and the community has correctly voted to reopen.