# Migration of Content from Open Science SE

Tags: discussion, migration

I just wanted to give you a heads up that I am about to start migrating selected questions from the [closure of the Open Science site](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/openscience-and-academia-qa-sites) to this site.

I would also note that you are under ***no obligation*** to keep any of these questions simply because they were chosen to be migrated. It is typically very unproductive to start a long, drawn out negation of what should be migrated ahead of time, so if you feel a question does not belong, simply vote to close it and the migration will be rejected. As always, if you have a question about how anything will fit into your scope, you can always raise the issue in meta. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, much appreciated! If possible, please try to avoid flooding our front page with migrated questions.

Comment: Is there a query to see all questions that were migrated to Academia from OpenScience in one place? It's interesting to have an overview of their fate here.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov Only for 10k+ users ([here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated&daterange=last14days)). Right now it appears as if 21 have been migrated and 0 rejected. You can see them with a [Google query](https://www.google.com/?q=%22migrated%20from%20openscience.stackexchange.com%22%20site:academia.stackexchange.com).